# What are the consequences of not closing open files in Python?

Tags: python, file, io

I've seen that the best practice for working with files in Python is to use the `with` block:

```
with open('file', 'r') as fi:
 text = fi.read()

with open('file', 'w') as fi:
  fi.write(text)
```

This way the files are automatically closed after you're done with them. But I get lazy, and in quick one-shot scripts I tend to do this instead:

```
text = open('file', 'r').read()
open('file', 'w').write(text)
```

Now obviously if I'm writing Real Software™ I should use the former, but I'd like to know what consequences the latter has (if any)?

Answer (score 6):

On CPython: None; the files will be closed when their reference count drops to 0, which is immediately when the `.read()` and `.write()` calls return.

On other Python implementations that do not use reference counting, the file will remain open until garbage collected.